# Why doesn't Regex \b metacharacter match Turkish characters at the end of the word?

Tags: regex, word-boundary

I am trying to parse words only using Regex in a string. This string contains Turkish characters which are `çğıİöşü`.

I tried `\b[\wçğıİöşü]+\b` regex pattern but it doesn't work totally well.

[image]

In the above picture I was expecting the pattern to be matched `Behiç` and `Güneş` completely. But it only matches `Behi` and `Güne` as you can see. What is the correct pattern to match `Behiç` and `Güneş`?

Comment: What regex engine did you used for the above (was it Regex101?) and specifically what _encoding_ does that engine use?

Comment: Yes you are right. The engine is Regex101. I have not enough information about the `Èncoding` of the engine. Sorry.

Comment: If you really need to use that regex flavour, you can use negative lookaround: [`(?<![\wçğıİöşü])[\wçğıİöşü]+(?![\wçğıİöşü])`](https://regex101.com/r/GoVhSr/1)

Comment: @horcrux While this might be logically correct, it doesn't address the encoding problem with the OP is having.

Comment: It does not work with `u` flag? [`/\b\w+\b/u`](https://regex101.com/r/0vrhN5/1) (also see [eval.in demo](https://eval.in/802225))

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen We don't know what kind of problem the OP has. He just talked about regex101, and my solution works on regex101 without changing the regex flavour.

Comment: @horcrux I was going to suggest using unicode literals in a character class (e.g. `\U00E7` for `ç`), but that also didn't seem to work with PCRE in Regex 101.

Comment: It's important to specify regex flavor. If you want to test c#/.NET, use such as [regexstorm tool](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cw%2b%5cb&i=Behi%c3%a7+G%c3%bcne%c5%9f). Regex101 supports php/pcre, python, js regex flavors.

Comment: .NET supports Unicode word boundaries by default. You would not even have to ask the question if you just tried the regex in the **target environment**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are getting is because the default regex mode in Regex101 is PCRE (PHP) with support for unicode characters turned off.  If you change the flavor to Python (q.v. the demo below), you will see the behavior you expect.

Just turn on support for unicode or UTF-8 and your problem should be solved.

## Demo

Comment: I am not targeting any platform, just trying to learn Regex detailed and improve myself. If I had a project I would develop it on .NET C# :) Thanks for help.

Comment: @AliTor Both .NET and Java (to my knowledge) would support targeting your Turkish characters using their unicode literals (e.g. `\U00E7` for `ç`).  You could consider this as an option later on.

Comment: [PCRE option supports any letters, just use the correct options](https://regex101.com/r/skmiLz/1).

Comment: Word boundary meta-character definition changes while using `u` modifier. Without `u` modifier there is no match when a leading `\b` exists here.